# Taking an unspecified number of inputs in c++

Tags: c++

I came across a question whereby you are told there will be unspecified number of queries hence you got to keep on taking input for this unspecified number of queries

all i know is that in c++ or even in another programming language, when the program needs to take unspecified number of input, we prompt the user to enter a certain value which will be used to terminate the infinite loop e.g

```
for (;;)
   {
     cout<<"enter 0 to stop taking input"<<endl;
     int value;
     cin>>value;
     if (value==0)
     {break;}
    }
```

my question is how will i handle the question stating the input will be unspecified and its in an online environment

Comment: What do you mean _unspecified_? You can always check if `cin>>value;` succeded like this `if(!(cin>>value)) { /* handle invalid input */ }`

Comment: click to accept my answer if it solves your issue, most online judges use pipe so that should do it!

Comment: by unspecified i mean an unknown number of input

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `while (cin >> a)` :

to see how if it works create an input file `1.in` and write a bunch of numbers in it, then pipe it to your executable fle `./a.out <1.in`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    while (cin >> a) {
        cout << a << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of problem you will use a loop control variable and a while loop for user input validation

*while loop* is use for input validation while *for loop* is use for specific

number of times only and it is not really suggested for unknown number of times

same with *while loop*, *do while loop* can also perform input validation the

only difference is, it will prompt the user first before evaluating the test condition

```
int myNum; // this is the loop control variable
cout << "enter a number, enter 0 to stop taking input " << endl;
cin >> myNum;

while(myNum!=0)
{
   cout << "cograts you did not enter zero digit" << endl;
   cin >> myNum;
}
```

Comment: program is being run on  online and the question does not allow for prompting to enter a certain digit for control of the input